# How to use one object's keyframe time as a driver?

Tags: animation, drivers, actions

I now have an object that has two keyframes, and I want to get the time of the second keyframe and use that as a driver for another parameter that controls the start time of the animation of the other object.

My current idea is to use the action in the driver, but searching the whole network did not find an example of using action to drive.

Can anyone give me a method, or use action to do an example of driving?

Comment: Hi liuran, i know you are pretty new here on the site, but a little hint: if an answer helped you, it would be helpful and nice, if you accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark left of the answer. By this other people also know that the answer helped you and is useful. Unfortunately commenting "thank you" isn't wanted here. So it would be nice if you could accept some of the answers of your old questions. thx.

Comment: Ok, thank you for reminding me!